# TypeError: Twit is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, twitter-api-v1

```js
const Twit = import("twit");
const notfier = import("node-notifier");
const open = import("open");

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         apikey,
    consumer_secret:      apiSecretKey,
    access_token:         accessToken,
    access_token_secret:  accessTokenSecret,
    timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
    strictSSL:            true,     // optional - requires SSL certificates to be valid.
  })

T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-07-11', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

I'm trying to use a Twitter API by js and Twit (Twitter API CLient) (https://github.com/ttezel/twit)
But I took TypeError: Twit is not a constructor error Here is my code below. What is the problem and what should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW8Cp.png)

I was expecting the search twitter for all tweets containing the word 'banana' since July 11, 2011

Comment: A dynamic `import(...)` returns a promise, not a constructor. The example uses `require`, not `import`

Comment: The `twit` contains commonJS, you can try `import * as Twit from "twit"`. Similarly, `node-notifier` looks commonJS. But `open` is probably ESM `import open from 'open'`;

Comment: Also, [you should not upload images of your code to StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Sorry you're right I'll be more careful.

Comment: Your code works well in my Windows 11, I am using node -v `v18.15.0` and npm -v `8.8.0`. I think your node environment is broken OR wrong API Key/Secret, Access Token/Secret. It's copied from  `https://developer.twitter.com/` 's  Get Twitter App.